# Site collection details in CA

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016

In CA, application management , view all site collections , click on site collection but the information is not displayed at the right side ?

[image]

Am I missing something? Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of reasons, but check this

1. Make sure content database exists on sql server...not deleted
2. Content database is online on the sql server not recovering state or not offline
3. If you able to access the site then run IISReset on the server which will bring the information back.
4. Some time refresh the content database with config db fix this.`$db = Get-SPDatabase | where {$_.Name -eq "DatabaseName"}
   $db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()`

Comment: Thanks Sir for your instructions, but the problem remains, any thoughts ?

Comment: R u able to browse the site collection? May be site is corrupted

Comment: yes sir,I can..!

Comment: In this case, i would try to detach the content database and re attach it

Comment: Sir it's a production , can i do that ?

Comment: it will cause outage, so do it after hours...But when you check the database status from the Central admin > upgrade migration > review database status....what is the status for that db?

Comment: No action required

Comment: what ahppen when you run get-spsite against that site collection? may be some permission issue on the db

Comment: Is it solved, typically IiS reset fix it